# How to update object property in Oridomi

Tags: javascript, object, oridomi

I am using a folding plugin called oridomi (oridomi.com). I create a new object, with some options passed.

```
var fold_map = new OriDomi('.fold-map', {
        vPanels:         8,     // number of panels when folding left or right (vertically oriented)
        speed:           0,  // folding duration in ms
        ripple:          0,     // backwards ripple effect when animating
        shadingIntesity: .2,    // lessen the shading effect
        perspective:     1000,   // smaller values exaggerate 3D distortion
        maxAngle:        40,    // keep the user's folds within a range of -40 to 40 degrees
        shading:         'hard', // change the shading type
        touchEnabled:    true
    });
```

I wanted to update the speed from 0 to 500 later on. I tried using:

```
fold_map['speed'] = 500;
```

and

```
fold_map.speed = 500;
```

But that's not working. I thought that's how you update object options in js. What's wrong?

You can fold/unfold the object using a method like:

```
 fold_map.accordion(30,'left');
```

Everything works, but I can't update the speed once it has been initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `setSpeed` method:

`fold_map.setSpeed(500);`

This method is also chainable as shown in this example:
http://oridomi.com/#queueing